# Windows mobile keeps restarting from time to time, sometimes it becomes sluggish

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

For some time I have been experiencing system restarts when os is in idle, or does some action in my app written in c# ...

1) Does anyone know if anything can be checked to discover what made the device to restart unexpectedly?

2) Also sometimes it starts working very very slow. There is only one app runnig. Even when I close it, the device still works very slow until I reboot the device..

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you are getting a low-level error you may find that the system will bog down to create a system crash dump.  This is usually from native or driver issues, not the kind of error you are causing directly with your .NET code (though referenced libraries are another story).  Might be worth checking for.

Answer (score 0):

You may have success in wrapping your application in a `try/catch` block.

```
static class Program {
  private static Form1 m_form;
  [MTAThread]
  static void Main() {
    try {
      m_form = new Form1();
      Application.Run(m_form);
    } catch (Exception err) {
      Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
    }
  }
}
```

Set a breakpoint at `Console.WriteLine(err.Message)` so you can see the error before the app crashes.

If this only happens in actual devices in the real world, write that exception message and stack trace to a simple text file.

Once you figure out what is causing the problem, fix it and take the `try/catch` block out.

Comment: This would go in your `Program.cs` file.